# Laravel: How do I pass data with redirect that can be used by the controller the GET request triggers?

Tags: laravel, redirect

I have a web page whose controller generates a unique code. Because of this on each page refresh a new code is created and this is not ok.

My solution to this was to use two controller methods

Method #1 creates the unique code and then redirects triggering a second controller method. This way on page refresh the #2 controller is re triggered and not #1.

Method #1 enters the code into a DB and method #2 pulls it and displays.

In order for this to work, I need to pass the DB id to the new controller method being triggered with 'redirect'.

Question: How do I pass data with redirect that can be used by the controller the GET request triggers?

---

### current code attempt

Controller method #1 return

```
//make unique code
//enter into db
return redirect("/confirmed/{$model->id}");
```

Controller method #2

```
public function confirmed($id) {
    $shipments = shipments::where('id',$id)->orderBy('id', 'desc')->first(); 
    return view('confirmed', compact('shipments') );
}
```

confirm route

```
Route::get('/confirmed/{$id}', 'ShipmentsController@confirmed');
```

Comment: If the code save in the database then it should not be created again?

Comment: Maybe you should use session instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can use session while redirecting,

```
return redirect("/confirmed/{$model->id}")->with('unique_code', $uniqueCode);
```

> **Note**: `$uniqueCode` is the code you have generated.

And then in other controllers you can retrieve it by `session('unique_code')`

```
public function confirmed($id) {
    $uniqueCode = session('unique_code'); 
    $shipments = shipments::where('id',$id)->orderBy('id', 'desc')->first(); 
    return view('confirmed', compact('shipments') );
}
```

I hope this will help you.